# How to change git repository using android studio

Tags: git, github, android-studio, version-control, repository

I'm using git with android studio and I already sync other repository.

But I hope to change a git repository like github.

I think I need to disconnect already connected to the repository but I don't found this option.

To do that, How can I do?

Comment: You could not explain your problem, try to explain your problem.

Comment: What are you asking explain more? I just want to change git repository. But I did not find any option my IDE(android studio).

Comment: Ok. I add more explain. : )

Comment: You want to use same project or want to checkout another?

Comment: I want to use same project but want to use github repo. (I already manage vcs other repo. ex : http://dev.naver.com/) Just not checkout.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to your project directory and delete hidding .git folder like shown below

you will be disconnected to git.

[image]

Answer (score 78):

We can change the repository url. Just follow the steps.

**In Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1**

1. Right click on project folder
2. From menu Choose **“Git”**
3. Then chosse **"Manage Remotes..."**
4. Now, select the existing **"origin"** and click on edit
5. Enter your new URL and click **OK**

**For Android Studio Older versions**

1. Right click on project folder
2. From menu Choose “**Git**”
3. Choose “**Repository**”
4. Choose “**Remotes**…”

[image: Git > Repository > Remotes...]

5. Now you got the “**Git Remotes**” popup

[image: Git Remotes]

6. You can edit the existing url or remove the old url and then add new url.
7. Click “**OK**”. that’s it. Now you are connected with new repo. But branches are not connected. Just follow few steps to complete.
8. Try to pull the changes from repo “**Git > Repository > Pull…**”
9. Now you got the “Pull Changes” popup. Click “Refresh” button.

[image: Pull Changes]

10. After successfully reconnected with repo then you can see the branches of new repo under “**Branches to merge**” box.

[image: Branches to merge]

11. ***Done. Now you are connected with new repo & branches***.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: i never got the old repo to accept anything, (thats why I want a new repo to try and fix stuff going to github). Q: Do I skip the branch steps since I got nothing out yet??

Comment: I thought every repository have master branch by default. so we can choose that. I am not sure about this.

Answer (score 21):

You can use **SmartGit** application and set your new git url at "**Remote\Properties...**" and then push button "**Store**".

Or you can go to "**[project folder]\.git**" and edit "**config**" file. Find line "**url = https//[your current url]**" and put your new url instead.

Comment: for Mac users to access hidden .git folder user cmd+shift+.(dot) and same combination to hide them back.

Answer (score 4):

**2021 method**

Tested on Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1

1. Right click on project folder
2. From menu Choose “Git”
3. Then chosse "Manage Remotes..."
4. Now, select the existing "origin" and click on edit
5. Enter your new URL and click ok

Comment: This is the correct answer for new versions of android studio.

Answer (score 0):

All answers above is okay, but after changing a remote url you want to make a new commit with all old files, yes? How to do it I made the video, see https://youtu.be/_ffZXwgA5oU

I just created a new Android Studio project and initialized a new git folder with new remote url repository, and then I just copied and paste all files from old project to new, see https://youtu.be/_ffZXwgA5oU

Answer (score 0):

**2023 method**

1. click on Git
2. click on manage remotes
3. then click on the URL and when you click on the pencil, you can
   paste  the  HTTP code which you got from the Code in your GitHub
   repository.

Comment: This looks the same as the other two answers from 2020?