# After deleting repo in github, Android Studio warns "...Repository not found.", how do I specify fetch from another repo in Android Studio

Tags: android, github

I click VCS → Git → Fetch in android studio, the event log print:

```
17:31   Fetch Failed
            origin: remote: Repository not found.
            repository 'https://github.com/xxxxxx/yyyyyy.git/' not found
```

Here the "https://github.com/xxxxxx/yyyyyy.git/" is a repository that I have deleted, but Android Studio IDE seem not to know that. What should I do to let Android Studio fetch from another existing repository?

Comment: Why are you trying to fetch when you have deleted the repository?

Comment: Because I don't know how to tell Android studio "the original repo has been deleted and you shouldn't point to it"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've deleted the remote repository and the fetch then obviously the remote repository will not be found. You need to change the remote's URL to your new repository.

Using SSH

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

Using HTTPS

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

If you want to do it through android-studio see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53913296/7641405